# The object won't be deleted

Tags: python, selenium

```py
from selenium import webdriver
    
class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        option.add_argument('headless')
        
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1700,1000)

    def __del__(self):
        print("delete object")
        self.driver.quit()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import chromedriver_autoinstaller
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install(True)
    a = Manager()
    print('a')
    del a
    input()
```

destructor is not called
Does anyone know about this problem??
I want to delete the object

Comment: It means that there is another reference to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

`del` does not destroy any objects, it simply unlinks a reference. If other live references to the `Manager` object still exist, or if the garbage collector has not run to clear up any cyclic references, `__del__` is not called.

If you want to guarantee some kind of cleanup action, your best bet is using context managers:

```
class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        option.add_argument('headless')
        
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1700,1000)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("exit context manager")
        self.driver.quit()
```

You can then use it like so:

```
with Manager() as a:
    print('a')
input()
```